# concatMap vs flatMap

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm confused by `prefetch` parameter from `concatMap` which basically sounds like `MAX_CONCURRENCY`.

> prefetch: the number of elements to prefetch from the current Observable

**Q1**: Does it mean to prefetch elements from `Observable` for mapping and then subscribe one at a time in order?

e.g, the docs for `concatMapSingle` is pretty clear:

> Maps the upstream items into SingleSources and subscribes to them one
>   after the other succeeds, emits their success values or terminates
>   immediately if either this Observable or the current inner
>   SingleSource fail.

**Q2**: Is it true that doc for `concatMap` can be reworded as:

> Maps the upstream items into ObservableSources and subscribes to them
>   one after the other completes?

The original version of a doc for `concatMap`:

> Returns a new Observable that emits items resulting from applying a
>   function that you supply to each item emitted by the source
>   ObservableSource, where that function returns an ObservableSource, and
>   then emitting the items that result from concatenating those resulting
>   ObservableSources.

i.e., the following lines are basically the same (in terms of `MAX_CONCURRENCY`)?

```
int MAX_CONCURRENCY = 1;
Observable.just(1, 2, 3).flatMap(num -> Observable.just(num), false, MAX_CONCURRENCY);
Observable.just(1, 2, 3).concatMap(num -> Observable.just(num));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Does it mean to prefetch elements from Observable for mapping and then subscribe one at a time in order?

In the current implementation of `concatMap`, upstream items are prefetched but are not mapped until the previous inner source completed (or it is the very first item). The inner sources are run one-by-one.

> Q2: Is it true that doc for concatMap can be reworded as:

I'd also mention the error behavior in the first sentence just like with `concatMapSingle`. PR welcome.

Some of the older javadocs are worded a bit convoluted, the newer ones are more snappy. Those old ones annoy me too, but unless they would need some expansion 
 - due to increased StackOverflow questions/misunderstandings about them - I tend to leave them alone.

> the following lines are basically the same (in terms of MAX_CONCURRENCY)?

With `Observable`s, there is no backpressure so both `concatMap` and `flatMap` have to queue up upstream items until they are ready to be mapped and subscribed to. `concatMap`'s `prefetch` hint should be more like `capacityHint` as it is used for sizing the internal queue holding the extra values.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: it's true. Found the answer [on GitHub](https://github.com/reactor/reactive-streams-commons/issues/21).

Comment: I wonder about `Flowable` whose `concatMap()` has `prefetch` parameter which defaults to 2.